# "Best" as a sign-off in a chat message

Tags: word-usage, dialects

A new colleague of mine, a native English speaker with whom I have only communicated via text, used "Best!" at the end of a chat message.

1. Does this signify anything to the extent of "this conversation is over"? Is it rude to end a message like this without a lead-in?
2. Does the usage of "Best!" allow any educated guess at what particular brand of English said colleague speaks (British, US-American, Australian, and so on)?

Comment: I would interpret that to mean "Best wishes!" But without researching it, I wouldn't be able to offer any info on the likely variety of English that would produce that expression.

Comment: I certainly end emails that way, sometimes. (British).

Comment: @ColinFine Do you intend "best" as a shortening of "best wishes" or of "all the best" or something else?

Comment: Haven't really thought about it. _All the best_, I think, because I would use that in a neutral context, whereas I would use _Best wishes_ when the other party is either celebrating something (like a birthday) or undergoing some hardship (like being ill).

Comment: You could think of it as being short for "Wishing you the best of everything!" I know people who use that, and when there is a frequent exchange of email (say like a conversation) it saves labouring over the sign-off every time. I do not see it as rude, but informal. It's similar in usage to "Cheers!" and "Love you!" etc as appropriate.

Comment: My US employer's default email signature begins "Best regards"

Comment: The upshot of all these comments is that there are lots of ways to close a conversation that involve the word "best", and this is just a shortened form of one of them.

Comment: It's a widely accepted, friendly but not too friendly, polite way to end any type of written communication. We use it constantly in the US, and my UK and Canadian friends and other contacts also use it all the time.

Comment: @IsabelArcher That sounds like it answers both of my questions. If you want to put it as an answer, I am willing to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @LokiRagnarok. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a native US English speaker who has lived for long periods in Europe. I have many friends and colleagues who are also native speakers of other varieties of English.

Based on my own experience, I can tell you that "Best" is very widely used in English-speaking countries around the world and in all types of online correspondence, whether email, chats, or other forms of social media.

I haven't often seen it used with an exclamation point, but there's nothing wrong with doing that. It's a question of personal style.

I would say that using "Best" is a widely accepted, friendly but not too friendly, polite way to end any type of written communication. And to answer your second question, I don't think it offers any clue about which variant of English the author speaks.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/best-as-a-letter-closing) notes that closing expressions like "Best wishes" began to be shortened to "Best" around the 1930s, and it cites correspondence by F. Scott Fitzgerald as an example. It then offers this to say about "Best" as a closing: "Certainly, there are critics of this 4-letter, elliptical valediction; however, to most its simplicity crisply connotes a sense of goodwill without sounding stuffy or disingenuous."

Answer (score 0):

1. It usually would not come off as ending a conversation forcefully because it’s a standard, neutral-positive way to sign off. In any context where you are writing your name at the bottom, like an email, with “Sincerely, warm regards, cheers, [name]”, you can use “best”. The difference with an SMS is you less frequently “sign off”. In this case the speaker seems to be politely signaling that the conversation is indeed over. So it could be socially negating if it was in an SMS and the person expected much longer continued interaction. In an email it would not be taken this way.
2. I personally think it’s slightly less common in the US but I might be wrong. I know it’s common in European International English (i.e. an English speaking company based in the Netherlands or something). In the US I found the most common email signatures to be Sincerely, Cheers, Kind regards, and especially “Thanks/Thanks very much.”